# How many calls would I have to score to determine what the Customer Satisfaction score is

Tags: statistical-significance, statistical-power

I run a call center.  If my baseline customer satisfaction score is 90%, how many calls would I have to audit and score to determine or predict what my Customer Satisfaction score is for a specific time study period? (usually a month).